# Datagrip ORACLE --- I cannot run Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, datagrip

When I run a Stored Procedure on datagrip IDE in oracle SQL i'm not able to see the return. It compiles, no errors, but I can't see the result. I think it's my fault, maybe I'm not calling it in the right way, i'm using the

> BEGIN ProcedureName(Parameter='Name'); END;

I've read about the

> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
> EXEC Media_Casi_totali ( Provincia =>
> xxxx );

But it seems not working for some reason. Is there anyone who can explain me how should I call the procedure and how should I check the result?

Comment: Procedures don't return anything. What are you expecting to see? Text from `dbms_output` calls perhaps? The `set` and `exec` are SQL\*Plus client comments, so not surprising those don't work. An `exec` is just shorthand for what you have in your first example. But do you actually have `='Name'` or `=>'Name'` in that call, as it would error with just `=` ?

Comment: Right, looking at your previous question, you are indeed expecting `dbms_output` displayed; so this is a duplicate. If you didn't catch the exception you threw then you'd see that error natively - the client/IDE would handle and display it.

Comment: Thank you, In the link u provid me it was explained how to see the output buffer and i got it. Anyway I didn't get the meaning of the "so this is a duplicate".

Comment: Just that a similar question has been asked before; and I closed this question as a duplicate of the one I linked to (and answered!). [That's a normal part of how Stack Overflow works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). Someone with a similar problem might find *this* question, and can also follow the link to that solution. Anyway, glad it's working for you.